# jQuery data value gets overwritten when updating data of another DOM element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I think I have a very serious misunderstanding of the jQuery data object. When I try to get and set a data-value (data-route) of a DOM element, other DOM elements with the same data-route but of course a different value, are getting overwritten as well?

To explain this, I have to tell you a lot:

I have a sidebar in which you can add link elements to a page. The way to do this is:

- You add an element by clicking on the green 'add-link' button. A new element gets added to the menu with jQuery's append function. (There is another function that sends the new link to the database, but that if not the issue here.)
- You can add limitless amounts of links, and each link has 4 settings: icon, color, background-color and ofcourse link-url. There are only 4 input fields in the HTML, so when you click on a different link item and open it up using the PLUS-symbol, I change the data in the input-fields by searching through a huge multidimensional array.

To get the correct value, I store the route of the array into the data-route of the corresponding element. When you add a new link, the array containing data updates, and so the data-routes have to be updated as well.

This is the point where it seems to go wrong.
I thought that every element has his own data-elements, but when I update element 1 of 4, the other 3 elements seems to have their data changed as well?

### Question

I loop through all elements that are of a certain class, here this is link-0;
With the function called 'changeDataSub' I loop through all the targeted elements and update the data-route of these elements.
When I do this for element 1, all goes well. I change the route from ['link-0','empty'] to ['link-1','0'].

When I then retrieve the data-route of element 2, the data retrieved is not ['link-0','empty'], but ['link-0']??
How come the data-value of element 2 to 4 also gets changed when I update element 1?

I have a 'working' example here: https://jsfiddle.net/abayob/fup90fq6/17/
When you add an element and click on the plus-symbol, you can see that the logged 'newRoute' value is different on the second loop compared to the first. This should stay the same...

### Javascript

Step 1: creating a new link element

```
$('#settings-accordeon').on('click', '#create-sublink', function(){
    var button = $(this);
    var group = button.closest('.panel-collapse');
    var groupRoute = group.data('route');
    var ul = button.siblings('.link_count');
    var name = button.data('name');
    var count = ul.children().length;
    var groupName = group.attr('id');
    var routeSource = $('#settings-accordeon .' + ul.data('target')+'>input').first();
    $('#settings-accordeon .link-' + count).removeClass('link-' + count).addClass('link-'+(count+1));
    var route = groupRoute.concat(routeSource.data('route'));
    count++;
    ul.data('target','link-'+count);

    //Dynamic set new route of element
    var tmpArray = routeSource.data('route');
    var last = tmpArray.pop();
    tmpArray.pop();
    tmpArray = tmpArray.concat(['link-'+count]);
    tmpArray = tmpArray.concat(last);

    $('#settings-accordeon .' + ul.data('target')+' [data-route]').each(function(){
        $(this).data('route', tmpArray);
    })

    var html = '<li class="_select-link_count " data-index="'+count+'">Links '+count+'<i class="fa fa-plus _delete-link_count"></i></li>';
    ul.append(html);

    //Make first one .selected
    if(!ul.find('li.selected').length){
        ul.find('li:first').addClass('selected');
    }
})
```

Step 2: opening the submenu:

```
$('#settings-accordeon').on('click', '._select-link_count  .fa-plus', function(){
    var that = $(this);
    var li = that.closest('li');
    var index = li.index();
    var target = that.closest('.link_count').data('target');
    console.log('click : '+index+', '+target);

    changeDataSub(that, target, index, li.hasClass('selected'));
})
```

The function that handles the changes: (THIS IS WHERE IT GOES WRONG)

```
function changeDataSub(that, target, index, openSub){
    var properties = $('#data').data('properties');
    var groupRoute = that.closest('.panel-collapse').data('route');
    index = index.toString();

    $('#settings-accordeon .'+target).each(function(){
        var value = properties;
        var that = $(this);
        var child = that.children('input');
        var newRoute = child.data('route');
        newRoute.pop();
        newRoute = newRoute.concat(index);

        child.data('route', newRoute);
        var route = groupRoute.concat(newRoute).concat(child.data('name'));
        // console.log(route);

        for(var i= 0; i< route.length; i++) {
            value = value[route[i]];
        }
        //console.log(value);
        child.val(value);
        if(openSub){
            if(that.hasClass('hidden')){
                that.removeClass('hidden');
            } else {
                that.addClass('hidden');
            }
        }
    })
}
```

### HTML

An HTML snipping with the needed data:

```
 <div class="panel-group" id="settings-accordeon">
        <div aria-expanded="true" class="panel-collapse collapse in"
        data-route="[&quot;foreground&quot;]" id="text-foreground">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <p>Links</p>
                <ul class="link_count" data-name="link_count" data-target=
                "link-0"></ul><br>
                <div class="settings-group hidden link-0">
                    <p>Icoon</p><input class="form-control" data-name=
                    "link_icon_type" data-route=
                    "[&quot;link-0&quot;,&quot;empty&quot;]" data-sub-model=
                    "true" data-value="" type="text" value="tree"><br>
                </div>
                <div class="settings-group hidden link-0">
                    <p>Tekst kleur</p><input class=
                    "swatch_selector form-control input-sm"                         data-name="color" data-original-title="" data-rerender=
                    "color" data-route="[&quot;link-0&quot;,&quot;empty&quot;]"
                    data-swatch-type="SWATCH_TYPE_COLOR" data-value="#000000"
                    title="" type="text" value="zwart"><br>
                </div>
                <div class="settings-group hidden link-0">
                    <p>Kleur</p><input class=
                    "swatch_selector form-control input-sm" 
                     data-name='background_color'
                    data-name="background_color" data-original-title=""
                    data-rerender="background_color" data-route=
                    "[&quot;link-0&quot;,&quot;empty&quot;]" data-swatch-type=
                    "SWATCH_TYPE_BACKGROUND_COLOR" data-value="#ffffff" title=
                    "" type="text" value="wit"><br>
                </div>
                <div class="settings-group hidden link-0">
                    <p>Link</p><input class="form-control" data-name="link"
                    data-route="[&quot;link-0&quot;,&quot;empty&quot;]"
                    data-sub-model="true" data-value="" type="text" value=
                    ""><br>
                </div><a class="btn btn-success" data-name="link" data-route=
                "[]" id="create-sublink">Voeg link toe</a><br>
                <a class="btn btn-danger" data-name="link" data-route="[]" id=
                "destroy-sublink">Verwijder link</a><br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-properties=
    "{"foreground":{"color":"#000000","form_email_address":"","link_count":"1","button_0":"create-sublink","button_1":"destroy-sublink","column_title_toggle":false,"title":{"column_title_centre_toggle":true,"column_title_pattern_toggle":true},"link-1":{"empty":{"link_icon_type":"tree","color":"#000000","background_color":"#ffffff","link":""},"0":{"link_icon_type":"tree","color":"#000000","background_color":"#ffffff","link":""}}},"background":{"background_color":"#ffffff","background_pattern":"none","background_pattern_transparency":0,"background_overlay_toggle":false,"overlay":{"background_overlay_color":"#000000","background_overlay_transparency":0},"background_image_toggle":false,"image":{"background_parallax_toggle":false,"background_cover_toggle":true,"image_upload":"http:\/\/placehold.it\/150x150&amp;text=afbeelding"}}}"
    id="data"></div>
```

Comment: Are you sure `that.children('input')` is not matching several `<input>` elements? If it is, the setter form of `data()` will impact them all in `child.data('route', newRoute)`.

Comment: I have tested it by logging the child.length value and even debugged the code with alert messages in between. There does seem to only be 1 element in the child-variable at all times